# Prove $K_{n,2n,3n}$ is Hamiltonian

Tags: graph-theory

So we know by theorom that the order $n ≥ 3$ and the min degree $≥ n/2$

So what I did was, $N = n+2n+3n = 6n$. Suppose $n=1$. Then $N = 6$ which is $≥ 3$.

The answer in the book says the min degree of the vertices is $4$? This is the part I am confused on; how do you get $4$?

This is a Hamilton cycle.

Comment: What is $K_{n,2n,3n}$?  Complete tripartite graph with parts of those sizes?

Comment: yeah - sorry should've been more specific

Comment: @NickPeterson I can only imagine so.  @ Miller21 For $n=1$ the minimum degree is in fact $3$ (*though this is largely irrelevant*) and the minimum degree in general is **equal** to $\frac{n}{2}$.  Note however that Dirac's theorem (*or Ore's theorem*) do not require minimum degree to be **strictly** greater than $\frac{n}{2}$, they require it be **greater than or equal** to $\frac{n}{2}$.  Your $>$ should have been a $\geq$.

Comment: @NickPeterson you are right.